# robot framework gives "no keyword with name" error after importing the python module which has the associated function

Tags: python, robotframework

**Test.py**

```
def test_method():
    print("hello")
```

**regression.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library               libs/Test.py
```

**test.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Resource              regression/regression.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Tvh1641513c

    Test Method
```

Please see the folder structure below.

- test_folder

  - libs

    - Test.py
  - resources

    - regression

      - regression.robot
  - tests

    - test.robot

I believe I'm importing the module in the robot file properly. But still I'm  getting the error "No keyword with name 'Test Method' found". It would be helpful if someone can advice on this.

Comment: Have you tried adding **def** before method name?:
`def test_method():
    print("hello")`

Comment: @AbdElRahmanZeid yes. I have added.

Comment: Please show the actual error.  Also, please provide a [mcve]. None of the code you posted calls `test_method` or `test method`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Please see the updated details.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Robot Framework user guide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id848).

Should define a class in `test.py`

```
class test:
    def test_keyword(self):
        print("hello")
```